# When to use ARIA IMG Role on sections with background images

Tags: accessibility

A client asked about fixing the problem of their background images not having alt attributes, and in response I suggested what we might need to do is support the IMG aria role on those sections.

I maintain a drag and drop builder product so when I implement this it should be clear to end-user when to provide a ARIA img role and descriptive label to a section.

I understand the general idea is to describe the background image when it's not purely decorative. Often a background image will be something related to the content and also decorative. When do you decide it is useful to add accessible contextual enrichment to a page section with background image?

Here are some examples of the sort of page sections I'm talking about:
https://demo.sooperthemes.com/glazed-main/sections-and-backgrounds

What I'm also worried about, if a section contains a bunch of text and a call to action, will it confuse the screen reader user if this section is labelled "img".

If the goal of the section is to have users sign up for some event, does that mean I cannot use ARIA img role to describe the background image on this section? Then what devices are left for me to describe a background image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally not good practice to add an ARIA role to a div with a background image. If an image needs a textual description, a more appropriate course of action would be to use the native HTML `<img>` element with an `alt` attribute.

> *Content authors and developers are therefore advised to use background images to render information only when native elements cannot be used.*
>
> https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/ARIATechnique_usingImgRole_with_aria-label_forCSS-backgroundImage

As a general rule, if the content makes sense without the image, or if image does not convey actionable information, then the image is probably decorative. Background images are not required to have text-descriptions, as they are part of the background, not the foreground.

The W3C provides some guidance on [what is a decorative image](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decorative/).

I don't see anything in the example provided that would necessitate a description of any background images.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do sometimes see clients use our advanced background options to place content into their page. For example because they like the parallax effect or because they prefer the clean look of a background video over YouTube's video player. in that context I think it is still nice to have the option to add the ARIA label.

Answer (score 0):

ARIA just isn't well supported.  You can't assign alt text to CSS background images.  That said, you can put them in a `<span class="visually-hidden">Photo of a dog on a picnic table.</span>` That should make the text invisible in a Drupal 8 site.  It's more complicated if you aren't using Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER use `role="img"` in this way, on a section which contains nested content.

I assume you're describing a structure similar to this:

```
<div id="fooSection" role="img" aria-label="foo" style="background-image: foo.jpg">
  <h2>My heading</h2>
  <p>Some more text</p>
  <a href="foo.html">Call to action</a>
<div>
```

> What I'm also worried about, if a section contains a bunch of text and a call to action, will it confuse the screen reader user if this section is labelled "img".

The effect is actually far more severe than that. The nested content *will not be conveyed to assistive technology at all*. In this example, screen reader users will be unaware of the heading, paragraph, and link. They won't be able to use the link either.

The reason is that the [ARIA `img` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.0/roles#img) is defined as having [presentational children](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.0/roles#childrenArePresentational), meaning that the descendants won't be exposed in the accessibility tree. Furthermore, the `img` role doesn't support [generating an accessible name from contents](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#namecalculation), so the only way to get a text alternative for the image is to use `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`.

If you can't avoid using a CSS background image, then you can use `<span role="img" aria-label="foo">` as a fake image element nested inside the section.

```
<div id="fooSection" style="background-image: foo.jpg">
  <!-- Text alternative for the background image on div#fooSection -->
  <span role="img" aria-label="foo"></span>

  <h2>My heading</h2>
  <p>Some more text</p>
  <a href="foo.html">Call to action</a>
<div>
```

Here I placed the fake image span as the first child of the DIV with the background-image. You have some flexibility in this; the fake image might make more sense if is came after the heading. This technique is documented in [Using ARIA: What If the Author Has to Have a CSS Image on a `<div>` that Contains Content?](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#the-effect-of-accessible-name-on-background-images), with the caveat that a HTML `<img>` is preferred.

> When do you decide it is useful to add accessible contextual enrichment to a page section with background image?

Most of the time, you will want to convey the image to everyone.

1. If the image is essential for a full understanding of the content, then you must provide a text alternative.
2. In many cases, the image might not really be considered *essential* for understanding, but it still deserves a text alternative. It may be supplemental illustrative material, or something which conveys a mood or impression. The key point here is that the choice of image was an editorial decision; it was chosen to *say something*. So that should be conveyed to everyone.
3. Beware of dismissing an image as "decorative" too readily. Pause to consider whether it is purely decorative, or whether it actually fits the previous category of illustrative, but not essential.  A technique I use is to ask: *"Would it matter if it was replaced by a different image?"* (For example, replacing a sports car with a rubber duck.)  If the answer is yes, then the image isn't purely decorative, and deserves a text alternative.